# Multiple CSS Animation alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been trying to trigger two animations placed at two different places  simultaneously to move them away from each other via JavaScript - `{{id}}.className`. But as soon as the animation begins, the second element with id - `p2` displaces automatically from its original position just before the animation starts.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPYYYm) is my Codepen link. And yeah, I'm using Bootstrap with this.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You remove all the `class` values from your two `divs` when you click on button.

So just replace :

```
e2.className = "pop2";
e1.className = "pop1";
```

By :

```
e2.classList.add('pop2');
e1.classList.add('pop1');
```

That will add the new `class` (pop1 and pop2) to the others existing by default (col-sm-7 and col-sm-5) and it work perfectly.

Comment: Or use `e2.classList.add('pop2')` ([check browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), though!)

Comment: yes that work also, thanks @GolezTrol updating my answer.